# How to make a QWidget based window have a transparent background?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, transparent, qwidget

Example code is [here](http://codepad.org/eJ7cnGap) and it runs like that, the image looks like:

[image: clock].

The main strategy is to use the `QBrush` to load a backgroud image that has a number and other stuff, the picture originally has the transparent background.

But how to make the `QWidget` window have a transparent backgroud has stucked me.

Answer (score 5):

In PyQt, you need to add the flag to all your existing window flags using the bitwise OR operator |, to make it work:

`window.setWindowFlags(window.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`

And then do
`window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)`

Remember to call the `show()` method after setting flags. Quoting the docs here:

*Note:* This function calls `setParent()` when changing the flags for a window, causing the widget to be hidden. You must call `show()` to make the widget visible again..

On the bitwise operator: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Hope that was useful.

*Edit:* Removed some incorrect information, Thanks to @ekhumoro's comments from below.

Comment: The `^` operator is the wrong one to use: it will remove the flag if it's already present. Always use `|` to ensure the flag gets set. Also, `setAttribute` does not toggle attributes: you have to explicitly pass `False` as the second argument in order to remove an attribute (i.e. `on` is `True` by default).

Comment: Thanks for that @ekhumoro. I have edited my answer to reflect the same. In the past I used the bitwise exclusive OR by mistake. It worked because I never re-set the flag using the same. Yes, | is the right way to go. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: The documentation was a little misleading: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setAttribute It said on if true, OTHERWISE it clears it. They must have meant if FALSE. They havent mentioned the default behaviour. Thanks for pointing that out too.

Comment: The line window.setWindowFlags(window.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) actually in the example in the other answer using PySide causes the window to disappear completely which is strange. Did you test this?

Comment: Yeah I have mentioned that in the answer. Quoting the docs here:

Note: This function calls setParent() when changing the flags for a window, causing the widget to be hidden. You must call show() to make the widget visible again..

If that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have a window (based QWidget) with transparent background you can to my knowledge only achieve this if you also make the window frameless.

The following example does that. Important are setting window flag `FramelessWindowHint` and setting attribute `WA_TranslucentBackground`.

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
window.show()

layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(window)
button = QtGui.QPushButton('Exit')
button.clicked.connect(app.quit)
layout.addWidget(button)

app.exec_()
```

Which only shows a freestanding button.

Comment: thanks , i have tried that, it have a black background .

Comment: @wanze Interesting. For me it's fully transparent. PySide and PyQt should be largely compatible. I also use Python 3.4 on Windows 7.

Comment: I am  in the Ubuntu system, and maybe the operating  system problem ? or the Video driver problem ?  I have to give it up now ..

Comment: @wanze Thanks for the hint. I will try tonight under Ubuntu. Maybe you just have to set some additional flags there maybe gnome/kde does not allow it, we'll see.