# "Blurred background" UI using Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt

Many apps today have part of their UI semi-transparent, with a blurred background, so you can kind of see colours behind a window.

However, I have not seen an example of achieving this with Qt. Is it achievable? If so, how can I do it? (A C++ or python example would be great).

Comment: related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497209/how-to-make-a-qwidget-based-window-have-a-transparent-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497209/how-to-make-a-qwidget-based-window-have-a-transparent-background)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transparent window with blur behind with pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807743/transparent-window-with-blur-behind-with-pyqt)

Comment: @musicamante No. The answer below the question uses a different library.

Comment: @MrUser read again, there are two answers to that question.

Comment: @musicamante The other answer relies on a non-Qt solution as well (e.g. on Linux, it uses `os.system` to invoke `xprop`).

Comment: @ekhumoro Gosh, sorry, I misread your comment and thought it was posted by the OP. The point remains, though, Qt doesn't provide that, the only way is through OS libraries (which is what that module does)